# Need to Increment Score in jQuery, how do I change the text

Tags: javascript, jquery, increment

I have to "Create a function, outside of the jQuery ready function, which increments the user's score when called and updates the HTML in `span#score`. I have the Variable. I have the function started but am not sure how to finish it so that it will change the text. I'm also not sure that I'm calling the function right in my `.ready` section.

I have this as part of a multiple question I put out a few days ago, but I really asked that wrong, too broad. I need to figure this out tonight. It's due at midnight but I'm sure he'll take it a little late. I think this is all the code I need to post. I think the rest would just be in the way, but let me know if you need it.

```
<script>
    var mole='<img src="img/mole.jpg"/>';
    var score=0;
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#score").click(increment);

    }); //end.ready

    function increment(){
        score+=1

    }; //end increment

</script>
```

Any help would be a true blessing at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `increment()` function is indeed increasing the score; all you need to do is actually output this back on the page. This can be done with `$("#score")[0].innerHTML = score`, as is seen in the following example:

```js
var score = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#score").click(increment);
});

function increment() {
  score += 1;
  $("#score")[0].innerHTML = score;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="score">0</div>
```

The `[0]` is needed because `$(#score)` (although targeting an ID) returns a NodeList collection of objects, and you want to access the first object in this list.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: How do I close it? Or did I by checking the answer? Oh, and how do you do the inline code? Last question, promise.

Comment: Questions are resolved automatically once you accept an answer. You can only accept one answer, but once you reach 15 reputation, you can vote up multiple helpful answers :) You can add code 'snippets' like this one here by clicking the code icon next to the picture icon when creating a question, though be aware that you can only add HTML, CSS and JavaScript this way. Other code can be added with four spaces preceding it, which can be shortcutted by highlighting the text and hitting `CTRL` + `K`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return` the increased value from the function. Also use `text` method to show the text in the DOM element

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

var score = 0;

function increment() {
  score += 1
  return score;
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#score").click(function() {
    var getIncreasedValue = increment();
    $("#textDisplay").text(getIncreasedValue)
  });

}); //end.ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="textDisplay"></div>
<button id="score">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the [execution context](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md) inside the [`jQuery.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) is set to individual DOM Element inside *jQuery's elements array*, you can also do something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('span#counter').on('click', increment);
  // or $('span#counter').click(increment);
})

var score = 0;
function increment() {
    this.innerHTML = ++score + '';
}
```

```css
span#counter {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 15px;
  line-height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="counter">0</span>
```